# How can I find a list knowing is name in the form of String?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have a lot of lists `List<String>` each one in a dart file. Every list contains the name of cities in various countries.

After choosing a country, I'm able to have the name of the list I want, for instance "list_cities_japan", as a `String`.

How can I a choose the good list to show the cities with this String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution would be to map your countries to the different Lists. Here is what that solution would look like in one file:

```
Map<String, List<String>> cities = {
    "list_cities_japan" : ["tokoyo", "Osaka", "kobe"], 
    "list_cities_india" : ["Delhi", "manglore", "kerela"]
}; 
  
  //prints complete map
  print(cities); 
  
  //print list of countries : (list_cities_japan, list_cities_india)
  print(cities.keys); 
  
  //prints cities in country list: [tokoyo, Osaka, kobe]
  print(cities["list_cities_japan"]);
```

Solution across multiple files:

1. File one

   ```
    List<String> list_cities_japan = ["tokoyo", "Osaka", "kobe"];
   ```
2. File two

   ```
    List<String> list_cities_india = ["Delhi", "manglore", "kerela"];
   ```
3. Main file

   ```
    import 'fileone'; 
    import 'filetwo'; 

    void main() {
      Map<String, List<String>> cities = {
      "list_cities_japan" : list_cities_japan, 
      "list_cities_india" : list_cities_india
      }; 

      //print list of countries :(list_cities_japan,list_cities_india)
      print(cities.keys); 

      //prints cities in country list: [tokoyo, Osaka, kobe]
      print(cities["list_cities_japan"]); 
    }
   ```

Comment: That means I have to put all my lists in the same file. There is no method to keep each list in a file?

Comment: @FloRaptor I've added the changes to work with multiple files, could you check it and verify the answer? thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! In fact it works well if we wrote something like `print(cities["list_cities_japan"]!); ` to avoid null return.

Answer (score 0):

Map all the countries to it's respective list of cities, something like:

```dart
  var map = [
    {
      'country': 'list_cities_japan',
      'cities': ['Hiroshima', 'Nagasaki'],
    }
  ];
```

And from there, you can access every list of cities of a given country

Comment: we can short it like map = {'list_cities_japan' : ['Hiroshima', 'Nagasaki']};